# CORS Error in Google App Engine on java server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cors, springboot

I have two apps.

Frontend(Angular) running on Firebase

Backend Spring Boot (Java11) running on App Engine

Got this error while trying to reach any endpoints in app engine `"Access has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"`

An interesting thing that, everything works fine in my local machine. No issues with cors. So, I guess the problem is in the configuration of app engine or smth else.

Could someone help me to solve this problem? I've already spent a lot of time trying to fix it. Already read a lot of stackoverflow similar issues. The last one: How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?

Can't find anything helpful in google docs.

app.yaml file

```yaml
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/<project_id>/locations/<location>/connectors/<connectors_name>
```

Here my config files:

CorsFilterConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsFilterConfig {
    
    @Value("${allowed-origin}")
    private String allowedOrigin;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> simpleCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList(allowedOrigin));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

`allowedOrigin` points to the `https://<firebase.domain>`

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
```

Endpoint example

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

---

I guess that you can't use app.yaml to control HTTP headers for dynamic
handlers. It is only applicable for static content

That's why this config fails to deploy with this error
`"Unexpected attribute "http_headers" for mapping type script."`

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/<project_id>/locations/<location>/connectors/<connectors_name>
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    http_headers:
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong URLs of allowed origin in my properties. So the config files and all cors configuration in my question are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the CORS needs to be allowed on the app engine app.

This can be done on the **app.yaml** by [adding a handler](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/config/appref#handlers_element) to include the CORS headers like this:

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/<project_id>/locations/<location>/connectors/<connectors_name>
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This will allow the CORS calls to come from any domain, if you want to have it more spefic to only allow your firebase app you can change the `*` to the firebase App URL

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the headers and need to respond to the request
Please try with the below code blocks

```
 header := w.Header()
 header.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Respond to the initial request

```
if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    return
}
```